# How to display a timer in user interface for android

Tags: java, android, layout

I am implementing an application in which i need to display a timer in the layout.The app continues like once the timer countdowns to 0sec then it should proceed to another app automatically whose path is defined.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code related to the Activity.

Comment: if u still have issues then add comment or accept the answer

Comment: the thing is that i need to display a timer from 10sec to 0sec....which indicate the user that the new application is goin to start in this many seconds....

Comment: @user1799482 u can achieve this functionality through the answer given below,is it done

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this and in onFinish load the other app

```
private class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
        long min = 0, sec = 0, totalSec = 0;
        totalSec = (millisUntilFinished/1000);
        min = totalSec/60;
        sec = totalSec%60;
        final long m = min;
        final long s = sec;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                System.out(" "+ m +"m and "+s+"s remaining.");
                                    // or Display the way you want
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //load the task you want to do
    }
}
```

can call it like this

```
MyCount counterr = new MyCount(sec *1000 , 1000);// sec = number of seconds
counterr.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have used `CountDownTimer` for this task.  Use the onFinish method to call other activity.

```
new CountDownTimer(timetocomplete, ticks) {
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {

           // Intent to start a new activity

       }
    }.start();
```